# How to get the hadoop home environment variable?

Tags: hadoop

How can I get the HADOOP_HOME & JAVA_HOME environment variable through the unix terminal ?

I know JAVA_HOME variable will be there in the hadoop-env.sh but how can I get through terminal?

Answer (score 2):

You can define it in global way by setting it in .bashrc file or it can be set in local hadoop-env.sh script in your Hadoop folder for example. If it is global you can check it by:

```
echo $HADOOP_HOME
```

If it is a script option, you can verify this variable by importing it into current context and checking it again:

```
. /usr/hadoop/bin/hadoop-env.sh
echo $HADOOP_HOME
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that these are set in your login script, or that you have already set them in some other way:

```
printenv HADOOP_HOME
printenv JAVA_HOME
```

or

```
echo $HADOOP_HOME
echo $JAVA_HOME
```

Comment: Yes, I have already set those while installing hadoop, but just want to know how to get through the terminal. For any environment variable is this the same command ? $NAME_OF_ENV_VAR.

Comment: @Venkat: I JUST told you! Yes, it is. And you can find this on Google.

Comment: @jason  What is the real purpose of giving hadoop location in bashrc to variables HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME,HADOOP_COMMON_HOME, HADOOP_HDFS_HOME,YARN_HOME,HADOOP_CONF_DIR,YARN_CONF_DIR ? Kindly help