# Hadoop 2.7.1 Eclipse plugin creation

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin, hadoop-plugins

After reading almost all the previous posts and web links, I feel to write this post as a need. I am unable to find any directory named ${YOUR_HADOOP_HOME}/src/contrib/eclipse-plugin in my windows based build of Hadoop 2.7.1. 
I have downloaded already compiled build from a source but as a matter of learning i want to build it myself. Is there any other way to have source files for creating Hadoop 2.7.1 eclipse plugin? or did i miss something at the time of building my own windows based hadoop? Please explain and if possible provide source for windows 7 build environment.

Thanks

Comment: What Hadoop is looking for is an [Environment Variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable). You might want to try out this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18195196/how-to-get-the-hadoop-home-environment-variable

Comment: Calon I am looking for source directory of eclipse-plugin in Hadoop new release 2.7.1 so to build it for making a Hadoop plugin rather than using a precompiled plugin

Comment: Then you might want to look at this: http://www.srccodes.com/p/article/30/build-hadoop-eclipse-plugin-jar-from-source-code-and-install-that-plugin-in-eclipse-ide. Older version, but it's worth a try. It says it's in the same palce like in your qeustion.